# Question about general properties of limits

Tags: limits

I am studying this result of Littlewood:

$$  \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n|=0 ~~.$$

The sequence $\{\gamma_n\}$ contains the imaginary parts of the zeros the Riemann $\zeta$ function in the upper complex half-plane.  It is known that there are infinitely many such zeros so there are infinitely many $\gamma_n$.  My question is very simple and I think the answer is "obviously yes" but I want to make sure I'm not missing some important detail.  Since I know $\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n\neq1$, can I immediately conclude that the order of the limited expression is of at most order $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$?

$$  \mathcal{O}(\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n)=\mathcal{O}(n^k)\quad\text{for}\quad k\leq-1~~?  $$

I'm asking if I can immediately reach this conclusion without knowing anything about $\{\gamma_n\}$ other than Littlewood's famous limit property.

Comment: Concluding it only from the information of the limit is zero? The limit of $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is $0$, but $n\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is unbounded.

Comment: @conditionalMethod You could please rephrase your question?  I'm not sure what you're asking, or what is the meaning of your following comment.  It seems like $\ln(n)/n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^0)$ and $n\ln(n)/n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^1)$.  What should I glean from this?

Comment: If you only know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$, then it could be that $f(n)\in\Theta(\frac{\ln(n)}{n})$. Then it cannot be that $f(n)\in O(n^{-1})$, since $n\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is unbounded.